# Transformed beta distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Let $Y\sim \operatorname{Beta}(a,b)$ and $X\sim \operatorname{Beta}(1,1)$ be independent. I am looking for a function $f$ such that $Y=f(X)$ in distribution. All I get is quite ugly, but I am quite sure it shouldnt be that bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that $\text{Beta}(1,1)$ is in fact the uniform distribution over the interval $(0,1)$, and its cumulative distribution function is simply $F_X(x)=x$ in that interval.

If you transform $W = g(X)$ with some continuous, strictly increasing function $g$, then
$$F_W(w) = P(W \le w) = P(g(X) \le w) = P(X \le g^{-1}(w)) = F_X(g^{-1}(w)) = g^{-1}(w).$$
Since you want $F_W$ to be the cdf of $\text{Beta}(a,b)$ (so that $W$ has the same distribution as $Y$), just take $g$ to be its inverse function, i.e. the quantile function of $\text{Beta}(a,b)$.

Now the beta quantile function does not in general have a closed form expression, so you will have to resort to numeric methods for it. (For example, Matlab `betainv` and R `qbeta`.) In some special cases a closed form exists, namely if $a=1$ or $b=1$ (see e.g. Sharma & Chakrabarty 2017: [Some general results on quantile functions for the generalized beta family](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/321451773_Some_general_results_on_quantile_functions_for_the_generalized_beta_family)).

Comment: +1 The Beta inverse CDF is not in general an easy calculation. See for example this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65975300/speed-of-random-sampling-from-distribution-in-r)